# How to change the view in AppDelegate didBecomeActive?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
   func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.



    let navVC = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

    if navVC.topViewController is ViewQuestionViewController {
       // Here I want the the view to be QuizTableViewController
      // so that navVC.topViewController is QuizTableViewController

    }
```

After the app become active ( `if navVC.topViewController is ViewQuestionViewController`) this becomes true. I want the  `if navVC.topViewController` as the `QuizTableViewController` so that after the app become active if it is not `QuizTableViewController` then it should become `QuizTableViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
let qui =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "QuizTableID") as! QuizTableViewController
var vcs = navVC.viewControllers 
vcs.dropLast() 
vcs.append(qui)
navVC.viewControllers = vcs
```

If you need to male Quiz the only vc inside the navigation with

```
navVC.viewControllers = [qui]
```